# "ERR_ASSERTION: A name parameter is required to create a storage" when using Salesforce SFDX CLI command 'sfdx force:project:create'

Tags: salesforce, ubuntu-16.04

following [the instructions to setup a salesforce dx prject](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_ws_create_new.htm), I get the error:

`ERR_ASSERTION: A name parameter is required to create a storage`

when using the command:

`sfdx force:project:create --projectname mywork`

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 (Xubuntu).

I don't get any hits on google when searching for "ERR_ASSERTION: A name parameter is required to create a storage" so any clues regarding that error will be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

adding package.json with the contents

```
{
    "name": "<anything I choose>"
}
```

Seems to allow it to work without the Mentioned Error (Although I have no Idea how that package.json should be written otherwise).

more related info on the [github issue](https://github.com/forcedotcom/salesforcedx-vscode/issues/253)

Answer (score 1):

Just as an update, I was running into the same problem and the issue was that there was a package.json in the root folder that shouldn't be there. Once deleted, the create-project process went through ok.